# How many times harder must one dog be pulling?

Tags: vectors, word-problem

> A sled is pulled forward by two dogs, each attached to the sled by a tow line. The angle between the two tow lines is $35^\circ$. How may times harder must one dog be pulling if the sled's path is at an angle of $20 ^\circ$ to the left hand dog's towline?

[image]

I decided to use the sine law:

$${r \over \sin (145)} = {b_1 \over \sin(17.5)}
\\ r = {b_1 \sin (145) \over \sin (17.5)}$$

and for the second diagram:

$${r \over \sin (145)} = {b_2 \over \sin(20)}
\\ r = {b_1 \sin (145) \over \sin (20)}$$

and set two equations equal to each other:

$$ {b_1 \sin (145) \over \sin (17.5)} = {b_2 \sin (145) \over \sin (20)}
\\ 1.9074 b_1 = 1.6770b_2
\\ 1.137 b_1 = b_2$$

Therefore, one dog must pull 1.137 times harder.

However the answer is supposed to be 1.32 times harder.

What did I do wrong? I assume that it is wrong to assume that the resultant vector is the same. But I cannot find a way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: What's the purpose of the first diagram? Where does the $17.5^\circ$ come from?

Comment: I divided 35 in half assuming the dogs are pulling the sled equally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is horizontal, the force exerted by the first dog is
$$(F_1\cos20^\circ,F_1\sin20^\circ)$$
and that by the second is
$$(F_2\cos15^\circ,-F_2\sin15^\circ).$$
The sum of the forces must be horizontal, so
$$F_1\sin20^\circ=F_2\sin15^\circ$$
so you can work out $F_2/F_1$.